# Decompose $X^{5}-2X^{4}+X^{3}-2X^{2}-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

#### Decompose $X^{5}-2X^{4}+X^{3}-2X^{2}-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

So far i've tried to use Eisenstein which failed, and i tried to decompose this with modular groups. With mod(2) we succeeded then we can decompose this polynomial in:

$$X^{3}(X^{2}+1)$$

In mod3 i failed.

Please help, if i am doing this wrong tips/hints would be very appreciated

Kees

Comment: A little question, is it $X^5 -  2X^{\color{red} 2} + X^3 -2X^2-2$ or $X^5 -  2X^{\color{red} 4} + X^3 -2X^2-2$ ?

Comment: its $X^{4}$ sorry about that, i'll edit it right away.

Comment: In $\mod 3$, this is just $\frac{X^6-1}{X-1}$. Note that $X^6-1$ is divisible by $X^2-1$ and by $X^3-1$.

Comment: This is a painful solution, but if you reduce it mod. 5, and look at all the polynomials of the form $X^2 + aX + b$ where $a,b\in\{0,\ldots,4\}$ you can check that these do not divide your polynomial in ${\mathbb Z}_5[X]$. Clearly there can't be a linear factor mod. 5 either (since there are no roots over the field), and hence it can't be decomposed mod. 5 (since there would have to be a factor of degree either 1 or 2).

Comment: For what it's worth, if the polynomial factorizes (and has no roots in $\mathbb Z$) then one of its factors is a cubic 2-Eisenstein polynomial (as the Newtom polygon shows).